# Overlapping text in side-by-side view of edit review queue

Tags: bug, review

While reviewing a suggested edit on [this question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68046831/2422776), I noticed that the question's title has a long, non-breakable word in it (specifically, `com.example.accountproject.models.interfaces.MemberSv`, a fully qualified Java class name). This causes the text of the two side-by-side posts to overlap:

[image]